# Sorting array in x86 assembly language

Tags: arrays, sorting, assembly, x86

I have to sort an array in descending order using parameters on the stack to an array and an array size.  I passed the size by value at `ebp+12` and the array by reference at `ebp+8`.

I know the code is kind of all over the place, but I'm just trying to get to something that works and I can try to clean it up from there.

I've been debugging and it seems to iterate through as I want it to, but my array isn't being sorted.  I've been banging my head against this for hours, so any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

The pseudo-code algorithm I'm trying to follow is:

```
for(k=0, k<arrlength-1,k++)
    I=K
    for(J=k+1,J<arrlength,J++)
      if(arr[j]>arr[i])
      I=J
    xchg(arr[k], arr[i])
```

And this is my attempt to implement it in x86 assembly:

```
;------------------------------------------------
sortlist PROC
;Sorts an array of specified size into descending order
;Receives: DWORD request value, address of an array
;Returns: array of size request, sorted in descending order
;------------------------------------------------
.data
first   DWORD   ?
next    DWORD   ?
.code
push    ebp
mov     ebp, esp
mov     ecx, [ebp+12]
mov     edi, [ebp+8]
mov     eax, 0
mov     ebx, 0
mov     edx, 0
mov     esi, 0

dec     ecx     ;loop for array length - 1
L1:
    add     edi, ebx              ;ebx = 0 first loop, 4 all remaining loops
    mov     eax, [edi]            ;get the value of the first element
    mov     first, edi            ;store address of first element in first
    mov     next, edi             
push    ecx
push    edi
L2:
    add     edi, 4            ;move to next element in array
    mov     edx, [edi]        ;set value of next element to edx
    cmp     [next], edx       ;compare element to next element
    jg      nxt        
    mov     next, edi         ;If less than, move address of greater to next
nxt:    
    loop    L2

    mov     eax,[next]        ;move values pointed to by 1st & next to regs
    mov     ebx,[first]
    mov     [first],eax       ;move values(swapped) to addresses
    mov     [next],ebx

    mov     ebx,4
    pop     edi
    pop     ecx
    loop    L1
pop     ebp
ret     8
sortlist ENDP
```

Comment: It seems that you are using `first` and `next` labels wrong. In fact, for such a simple algorithm you should not need to use any memory outside of your data array and the registers.

Comment: Thank you, I'll re-think my approach and try it without using any local variables.  That was my original plan and I ran out of registers to use but I'm sure there are easier ways to go about it

Comment: In your pseudo-code, what's the capital-`I` variable?  It's not used, and the lower-case `i` array index is unset.  Super confusing.  Or are they the same variable?  That would make this just SelectionSort, where you find the smallest or largest element in the rest of the array and swap it into place.

Comment: And BTW, registers *are* local variables.  Labeled locations in `.data` are global / static variables.  Use comments to keep track of what logical variable is in which register.  (And if you run out of registers, spilling something that you only read is normally best, like `arrlength`, so you can just use a memory-source `cmp` instruction.)

Comment: Yeah sorry for the typo in the pseudo-code, its copy-pasted from my instructor's assignment page, the upper and lower i should be the same.  Thank you for the info on local variables, I was under the impression that as long as it wasn't declared in main's .data it would be local, but that makes sense!  I've been working on another class just to step away from this a bit, but I think your suggestion on keeping better track with comments will help me not get lost in the code again.  Thank you for the suggestions!

Comment: @TimPalecek - Would you like me to provide you with an example code where I don't use any local variable and only registers?